# How to view a list of names in a collection in the console with meteor

Tags: meteor

How do I view a list of all the names in a collection.

In the example below I want to see a list of every **synth + counterDivItem** in the console. I know how to view the numbers of a given entry using **savedState.find({}).count();**  but I don't understand how to actually see a list of the names.

```
savedState.insert({Category:"SYNTHS", items: [{Name:"synth" + counterDivItem }]});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a forEach on the find cursor and iterate through the items, pushing the value of Name to the list.

```
var list = [];

savedState.find().forEach(function(state){
    for (a = 0; a < state.items.length; a++) {
        list.push(state.items[a].Name);
    }
});

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Bonus: Use the underscore smart package by doing `meteor add underscore` and the iterating functions provided, if you want to keep your code cleaner

Comment: Meteor used to rely heavily on underscore and thus you didn't need to add it yourself, did they remove it from the core packages?